# Vuejs VueFormGenerator focus input field

Tags: vuejs2

I am using VueFormGenerator and i want a focus for example poscode field. I can't find it on their website https://icebob.gitbooks.io/vueformgenerator

How can i achieve this?

```
schema: {
        fields: [{
            focus:true,
            id:"zaw-postcode",
            type: "input",
            inputType: "text",
            model: "postcode",
            placeholder: "Postcode...",
            label: "Postcode",
            required: true,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.postcode,
            hint: "Example: 1234 AB",
        }, {
   etc
   etc
   etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
attributes: {'autofocus':true}
```