# How to focus the cursor on the first input in vue template form generator?

Tags: vue.js

The example I am using can be found on the example in the readme of this page:

https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator

I am trying to get the cursor to focus on the first input in a vue form generator, which in this case would be Name.

So far I have tried adding `attributes: {'autofocus':true}` to the schema suggested in [Vuejs VueFormGenerator focus input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089696/vuejs-vueformgenerator-focus-input-field) like so:

```
schema: {
            fields: [{
                        attributes: {'autofocus':true}, ...
```

but it doesn't focus.
I've also tried to put ref tags somewhere, so I could do something like this.$refs.refname.focus() but it doesn't seem to be anywhere to put it.

Any ideas?

Here is the Javascript code:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    
    components: {
        "vue-form-generator": VueFormGenerator.component
    },

    data() {
            return {
        model: {
            id: 1,
            name: "John Doe",
            password: "J0hnD03!x4",
                        age: 35,
            skills: ["Javascript", "VueJS"],
            email: "john.doe@gmail.com",
            status: true
        },
        schema: {
            fields: [{
                type: "input",
                                inputType: "text",
                label: "ID",
                model: "id",
                readonly: true,
                featured: false,
                disabled: true
            }, {
                type: "input",
                                inputType: "text",
                label: "Name",
                model: "name",
                readonly: false,
                featured: true,
                required: true,
                disabled: false,
                placeholder: "User's name",
                validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string
            }, {
                type: "input",
                                inputType: "password",
                label: "Password",
                model: "password",
                min: 6,
                required: true,
                hint: "Minimum 6 characters",
                validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "number",
                label: "Age",
                model: "age",
                                min: 18,
                validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.number
            }, {
                type: "input",
                                inputType: "email",
                label: "E-mail",
                model: "email",
                placeholder: "User's e-mail address",
                validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.email
            }, {
                type: "checklist",
                label: "Skills",
                model: "skills",
                multi: true,
                required: true,
                multiSelect: true,
                values: ["HTML5", "Javascript", "CSS3", "CoffeeScript", "AngularJS", "ReactJS", "VueJS"]
            }, {
               type: "switch",
                label: "Status",
                model: "status",
                multi: true,
                readonly: false,
                featured: false,
                disabled: false,
                default: true,
                                textOn: "Active",
                                textOff: "Inactive"
            }]
        },

        formOptions: {
            validateAfterLoad: true,
            validateAfterChanged: true
        }
            };
    },
    
    methods: {
        prettyJSON: function(json) {
            if (json) {
                json = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 4);
                json = json.replace(/&/g, '&').replace(/</g, '<').replace(/>/g, '>');
                return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function(match) {
                    var cls = 'number';
                    if (/^"/.test(match)) {
                        if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                            cls = 'key';
                        } else {
                            cls = 'string';
                        }
                    } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
                        cls = 'boolean';
                    } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
                        cls = 'null';
                    }
                    return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>';
                });
            }
        }
    },
});
```

The full code can be found at: https://codepen.io/zoul0813/pen/OrNVNw

Edit: changed id to name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can not focus the ID field because it is disabled and read only.
Second since you can't add a ref you need to access is via getElementById like
`document.getElementById("id").focus()`

here the codepen: https://codepen.io/mxmstolz/pen/WNXXyrr

Comment: I didn't realize ID is disabled, so in this case focus to Name field instead

Comment: then just replace the `id` with `name` in the mounted hook

Comment: I don't think there is a mounted hook in this, where should I add it

Comment: check my linked codepen in the answer